# In Rails 4.1, how to find records by enum symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Assume I have this model:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :active, :archived ]
end
```

How can I find all active conversations without using the numeric value of the enum or without having to iterate over each conversation?

I tried doing `Conversation.where(status: :active)`, but it didn't yield any results.

The only solution comes to mind is to iterate over all conversations and select the active ones, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

```
Conversation.all.select {|conversation| conversation.active? }
```

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: It will work in Rails 5 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19964

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Enum` provides scopes based on its values.

Just try:

```
Conversation.active
```

or

```
Conversation.archived
```

Of course, you can create your own scopes as [Kyle Decot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/435471/kyle-decot) mentioned.

Comment: Not really a solution if you are passing that type value as a string say via an API request or query string value.

Answer (score 48):

This works great:

```
Conversation.where("conversation.status = ?", Conversation.statuses[:active])
```

For some reason this does NOT work:

```
Conversation.where(status: :active) #searches for NULL
Conversation.where(status: 'active') #searches for status=0 no matter what the enum
```

### Update

All the above statements work with Rails 5. Happy coding!

Comment: Note that Rails 5 will allow all these statements to work. Woo!

Comment: The answer can be rewritten as `Conversation.where(status: Conversation.statuses[:active])`. No need for strings.

Comment: Just switched back to work on a Rails 4 project and thought I was going nuts. Thank you for noting that these are Rails 5 conventions.

Comment: Unfortunately Rails 5 doesn't fix querying through a parent (e.g. `Person.joins(:conversations).where(conversations: {status: :active})` errors out). Have to use the first method for that yet (`Person.joins(:conversations).where(conversations: {status: Conversation.statuses[:active]})`).

Answer (score 28):

[ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) provides built-in scopes based on the values so you can simply do:

```
Conversation.active
Conversation.archived
```

Comment: ASAP, enum creates scopes like this by default, so if you have `enum status: %i[active archived]`, you already have `.active` and `.archived` scopes.

Comment: Kensuke Naito's solution below is much better

Answer (score 8):

```
Conversation.where(status: Conversation.statuses[:active])
```

Comment: No need to create a new instance - `Conversation.statuses[:active]` should work

Comment: Nice!, this way I can do  "or" expressions: Conversation.where(status: [Conversation.statuses[:active], Conversation.statuses[:archived]])

Comment: Also, if you wanted the opposite (ie. all records where status is anything other than active): Conversation.where.not(status: Conversation.statuses[:active])

Answer (score 4):

Did you try `Conversation.where(status: [:active, :archived])` ?
As listed [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Comment: This one never worked for me. Everytime i have to match every record with the same state as my object I have to do `Conversation.where(status: Conversation.statuses[my_conversation.status])`. Any idea why it doesn't work ?

Comment: @Logar Maybe isn't supposed to.. 
Check https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19964

Comment: Hehe, I got lured by documentation. At least now I know !

Comment: Conversation.where(status:
      [Conversation.statuses[:active], Conversation.statuses[:archived]])

Answer (score -8):

try this:

```
.enum :status => {:active => "active", :archived => "archived"ok_off => "took off"}
```