# My Enums is not working on where clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have the following model

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Enumerables
    enum status: [:pending, :accepted, :completed]
end
```

and the migration looks like this:

```
class CreateRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :requests do |t|
            t.column    :status, :integer, default: 0, index: true
        end
    end
end
```

Simplified, for the sake for the question.

Now, everything about my Enums works fine.

```
@request.pending?
@request.accepted!
# And so on...
```

But when I do the following query:

```
Request.where(status: :accepted)
```

This is what my log shows:

> SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."status" = NULL LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

This is obviously wrong, because of the `NULL`. Now I know I could do this

```
Request.accepted
```

But the other way should work as well, as explained in [the documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

What is happening??

Comment: Those are not enumerables, they're enums. Big difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that the feature I was trying to use is not available because I have been reading the `Edge` version of the documentation, which is probably still not released. Dumb error.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
accepted_requests = Request.accepted
```

reference: [In Rails 4.1, how to find records by enum symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101009/in-rails-4-1-how-to-find-records-by-enum-symbol)

Comment: In that case, the log says: `SELECT  "requests".* FROM "requests" WHERE "requests"."status" = ? LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0  [["status", 1]]` which I guess it is correct, but the other way should work as well, no?

Comment: no this link http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html explains the reason. and i quote: `Note that when an Array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array. In the example, :active is mapped to 0 as it's the first element, and :archived is mapped to 1. In general, the i-th element is mapped to i-1 in the database.`.. will this work `Request.where(status: [:accepted])`

Comment: major reason is bcoz they are mapped to integers in database not by value. so when you pass string to query on integer it wont work. read first line `Declare an enum attribute where the values map to integers in the database,`

Comment: But I declare the enum like in the documentation. And the documentation tries to do a where, exactly as I did it. So where is the difference?

Comment: yes but documentation does not say that you can query on Model with string as condition. actually enum first have to map the status you pass in array into the integer in the same order of array and based on that integer it query the table using that integer as the type of status in database is also integer not string. i guess you are missing the part of integer in table and string in query. moreover. that is why Enum provides you to call status as scope it self to make things easy

Comment: document said this `Record.statuses[:accepted]` this will return you the integer in your case 2 i think. now this you can use to query table..

Comment: Actually, it does say it. Watch the 3rd yellow block in this link http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: actually that is the thing that only `edgeapi.rubyonrails.org` is suggesting which i guess is wrong. this is the http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html link to api docs which i also checked and nothing like this... also i read this article. and he explicitly said that it wont work https://hackhands.com/ruby-on-enums-queries-and-rails-4-1/ as it is expecting integer nor string