# Find all records that contain one join model but not another using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following schema in my rails app.

```
class Campaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :businesses
  has_many :clients, through: :businesses
end

class Business < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clients
  belongs_to :campaign
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :business
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client

  enum category: {
    :processed,
    :delivered,
    :opened
  }
end
```

I need a way of finding all clients in a campaign that have a processed and delivered event category but **not** a opened category

My naive way of doing this was:

```
c = Campaign.first
c.clients.joins(:events).where('events.category' => [0, 1]).where.not('events.category' => [2])
```

But this won't work.

This query will run across some pretty big tables so eager loading isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try these as enums cannot be normally compared like basic strings.

```
c = Campaign.first
c.clients.joins(:events).where.not("events.category = (?)", Event.category[:opened] )
```

or just

```
c = Campaign.first
c.clients.joins(:events).where("events.category = (?)",[ Event.category[:processed], Event.category[:delivered]] )
```

More Info can be find [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)

You can also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29135693/7046734

Comment: Thanks but that still won't help here. I'm already using the raw enum value in the query, the problem is still the same.